# plotting diffrent curves in one plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to make a plot in Matlab like [this](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S002189281100061X-gr5.gif).

How could I do something like this in Matlab?

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you provide some data and at least show that you've tried to plot a single curve? `hold on` and `plot` should get you started

Comment: Is this supposed to be a 3D plot (with 3 linearly independent axes), or a 2D plot with 3 non-perpendicular axes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make some data:

```
x = 1:0.1:100;
y = 1:5;
for i = y
    z(i,:) = sin(i*x);
end
```

Plot it:

```
figure
hold on
for i = y
    plot3(x,i*ones(size(x)),z(i,:))
end
```

Modify the plot aspect and view:

```
daspect([100,2,2])
view(45,60)
```

Does that do roughly what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command plot3(X,Y,Z).

You have to build three matrices each one containing a number of column equal to the number of series you need. (6 in the figure you sent)

For example

```
X = repmat([-200:200]',1,6);
Z = rand(401,6)*10;
Y = ones(401,1)*[1:20:120];
plot3(X,Y,Z)
axis image
```